# Sharing SparkContext across multiple Spark Streams in Spring-XD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spring-xd

Can two Spark streaming processor modules share the same SparkContext (not the streaming contexts) within the same XD container?

Comment: I don't know Spring-XD, but http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Multiple-SparkContexts-in-same-Driver-JVM-td20037.html suggests against this in the same JVM. Maybe you could take a look at the Job Server?

Answer (score 0):

No, an XD container can only have a single SparkContext (and in turn the SparkStreamingContext) running. Since Spark doesn't allow you to have multiple SparkContexts on the same JVM until at least this ticket is resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243

Spring XD limits the XD container to have only a **single** XD spark streaming module (irrespective of whether it's a processor or a sink)

For more information you can look at this implementation that constructs the SparkStreamingContext (and thereby the SparkContext):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/plugins/spark/streaming/SparkStreamingPlugin.java

and, this one that restricts XD container to have only a single Spark streaming XD module:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/spark/SparkStreamingContainerFilter.java

Let us know if you think you have a better strategy to do this and follow up on JIRA. Thanks!